# Purpose of default startfiles and linker scripts in arm-none-eabi toolchain?

Tags: arm, embedded

Arm-none-eabi toolchain is always used with -nostartfiles flag to exclude default crt's and with custom linker script per each microcontroller, so what is the purpose of default ones of them (which are under /usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/)? When do they used?

Comment: just like on every other platform.  When you build natively.  gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world

Comment: To answer your question, 'none-eabi' is configure for [newlib support](https://sourceware.org/newlib/).  It needs you to implement a limited set of functions and then the default enviroment will allow you to use many of the 'C' library functions on an embedded platform. Specifically, you need to implement the [syscall functions](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls) or avoid using some 'C' library functions... and this is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any circumstances that you would use the default linker script unedited, although it is a useful template to set up your own version.

The default start files contain initialization routines that you may or may not need.

If you are compiling for C only and you do not use any C library functions which are impure then you can get away with -nostartfiles, however if you are using C++ or library functions which keep some state then the start files may perform necessary initialization.  You can read the source of your C library for details.

If you write your linker script by hand then there is really no need to specify -nostartfiles because you can have more fine-grained control over what is included and excluded in the linker script.  Having the startfiles available as linker input is harmless if you use the --gc-sections linker option to remove everything that is not referenced.

For example, many embedded targets are intended to boot and run forever and never shutdown/finalize/exit.  You can exclude .fini and related sections in your link script without risking missing something that you need by using -nostartfiles.

The best way to look at this is to compile a real project that you are working on with and without the option and see if there is any difference in the map file or disassembly.

Comment: You may wish to look at my comment in the question to improve your answer.

Comment: Your comment is mostly true, but I don't see anything in it that is related to the question.  arm-none-eabi usually uses newlib but doesn't have to.  If you do use newlib you don't have to implement the system calls unless you use certain impure functions as I already said in my answer.  Eg: strlen is pure, you can use this without defining syscalls.  malloc is impure, you need to define sbrk.  Newlib's malloc doesn't need any initialization apart from maybe copying initialized data and zeroing bss but there may be other impure functions that do.  If you use one you shouldn't use nostartfiles.

Comment: newlib is the answer to the only question the OP poses, *When do they used?*  or 'When are they [default linker script] used?'  or the question title 'Purpose of default startfiles and linker scripts in arm-none-eabi toolchain?'

Comment: I found interesting [blogpost](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2019/04/17/exploring-startup-implementations-newlib-arm/) about newlib and it's startfiles. As I understood from this post, newlib's startfiles does not perform any initializations exept of bss zeroing, so they can be excluded. Default toolchain's linker scripts can be used only for debugging using semihosting.

Comment: I didn't want to go into the details in a stack exchange answer, but the link is helpful!  One example of why you have to have the startfiles is __libc_init_array calls init which requires the startfiles (even though it is probably does nothing).  If you don't call __libc_init_array then your initializers don't get called for global C++ objects.  Obviously you can call them yourself in some other way but then you are re-inventing the wheel just to save about 12 bytes of flash in the .init section.